# LINQ as a method parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple object like this

```
public class Test
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Later I have `List<Test> tests`

And then I have a method which does something with a `Test` object in the List.

```
private void DoSomething(Test test)
{
   //do some serious stuff here!
}
```

Then in the applciation, this `Test` objects will be populated in a TreeView and after user clicks them they will be passed to the method above. At the moment I find selected treenode like this:

```
string name = selectedNode.Text;

foreach(Test test in tests)
{
   if (test.Name = name) DoSomething(test);
}
```

So the idea is, I cant figure out a way to use LINQ in the parameter of the method instead of doing that boring foreach loop.

```
this.DoSomething(from x in tests where x.Name = "What I need to pass" select x)
```

what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use LINQ as a parameter in the method, the same way you can't use anonymous types.

Comment: Even if I cast (Test) before the linq in the parameter?

Comment: sorry I meant in the foreach loop this:   `if (test.Name = name) DoSomething(test);`

Comment: If you only need/expect 1 Test then call `DoSomething((for ...).Single())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.DoSomething(tests.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="What I need to pass"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively doing a search here.  Assuming the names are unique, you could do this:

```
var selectedTest = tests.SingleOrDefault(test => test.Name == selectedNode.Text);
if (selectedTest != null)
{
    DoSomething(selectedTest);
}
```

Comment: Well this was not so different from the foreach loop I am already doing. I am looking for using linq directly as the parameter.

Comment: In what way is this not different from using the foreach loop?  The verification?  Why would you want to omit that?  IMO it would be better to verify before calling your private methods rather than verify in them.

Comment: yeah you are right about the verification...it shouldnt be omited. I was just courious about using linq in the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A linq query results in a IQueriable object. So you could use that as argument.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below would work. I wouldn't recommend it though unless you checked for null cases in the DoSomething method. You should run the LINQ query first store the results and check them before passing them to a new method.

```
this.DoSomething(
     (from x in tests 
      where x.Name = "What I need to pass" 
      select x).FirstOrDefault() as Test);
```